# How would one prove that $L^3$ is reflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have no idea where to even start with this. I think the idea should be that we need an isomorphism from $L^3\to (L^{3/2})^*$ and then an isomorphism from $(L^{3/2})^*\to (L^3)^{**}$, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: Here's another approach: show that $L^3$ is uniformly convex, which by the Milman-Pettis theorem implies that the space is reflexive.

Comment: I don't have that much of a background, and hence do not know what uniformly convex means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [duality properties of $L^p$ spaces](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-06-dual-lp.pdf):
$$
(L^p)^{**}= (L^{p'})^* = L^p,\qquad \frac1p + \frac 1{p'}= 1,\qquad 1<p<\infty.
$$

EDIT: [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces).

For $g\in L^{p'}$ we define
$$k_p(g): f\longmapsto\int fg.$$
Can be proved that $k_p(g)\in (L^p)^*$ (easy) and that
$$k_p:L^{p'}\longrightarrow (L^p)^*$$
is an isometric isomorphism (less easy). Finally, the composition
$$(k_p^{-1})^*\circ k_{p'}: L^p\longrightarrow (L^{p'})^*\longrightarrow (L^p)^{**}$$
is an isometric isomorphism and coincides with the canonical embedding in the bidual.

Comment: I need a proof of this.

Comment: @HughMungus, see the added link.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated

Comment: One should be careful with this answer. I would interpret "$X = Y^*$" as "$X$ is isomorphic to the dual of $Y$". Then, the statement $(L^p)^{**} = L^p$ is not enough to conclude that $L^p$ is reflexive. It merely shows that $L^p$ is isomorphic to its own bidual, and this is not enough to conclude reflexivity.

Comment: @gerw, see the edit.